# Does making an application shortcut from a webpage affect localstorage/cache clearing?

Tags: html, mobile

If, on both iOS and Android, a user makes a homescreen/app draw shortcut to a webpage, does it save that site's cached items and localstorage so they won't be removed when a user manually clears app cache, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - tested on an iPhone 5 on iOS7 and a Nexus 4 on 4.3